# FFMPEG Audio stream/layer and SRT from one mkv to an other

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, merge

I have an FFMPEG question for you!

**Problem**:

I have 2 files(x265)

01.mkv with multiple audio steams and multiple subtitles (with exactly named layers)

02.mkv with multiple audio steams and multiple subtitles (with exactly named layers)

I would like to add specific audio layer(GER) and specific subtitle(GER)
from 02.mkv to 01 mkv at the same time if it is possible.
(The metadata positions almost always random in file 02.mkv so I can't say it is "-map 0:s:2 for ger subtitle"...)

**I have already searched and tried multiple solutions ...**

This kind of worked with multiple steps but loses audio and subtitle metadata(Title) during process.

German audio layer extract from 02.mkv to aac

```
ffmpeg -i 02.mkv -map 0:a:m:language:ger 02.aac
```

German subtitle layer extract from 02.mkv to srt

```
ffmpeg -i 02.mkv -map 0:s:m:language:ger 02.srt
```

Adding extracted audio to 01.mkv

```
ffmpeg -i 01.mkv -i 02.aac -map 0 -map 1 -codec copy outputfinall_1.mkv
```

Adding extracted srt to 01.mkv none of this works

1.)

```
ffmpeg -i 01.mkv -i 02.srt -c copy -c:s mov_text outputfinall_2a.mkv
```

BUG: Subtitle encoding currently only possible from text to text or bitmap to bitmap

2.)

```
ffmpeg -i 01.mkv -i 02.srt -map 0 -map 1 -codec copy outputfinall_2b.mkv
```

works but does not show subtitles while playing only that is there.

**Please if you can help I would like a less jumbled mess code for this problem.**
*With keeping the metadata (titles) of the moved audio stream and subtitle.*

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Try : `ffmpeg -i 01.mkv -i 02.srt -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -c:s srt outputfinall_2b.mkv`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -i 01.mkv -i 02.mkv \
  -map 0 -map 1:a:m:language:ger -map 1:s:m:language:ger \
  -c copy outputfinall.mkv
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "metadata (titles)", posting the log of the above command with clarification will help understanding your situation.

Comment: Thank you it worked wonders! But the output file becomes choppy with the new audio lane is there any solution to that.(I have tried with the latest FFMPEG and the last stable one too. )